# How to avoid InnoDb shortcomings for non-unique foreign key columns?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, innodb

I have a MySQL table that contains translations for our System:

```
| topicID | languageKey | text            |
-------------------------------------------
| 1       | EN          | Hello!          |
| 1       | DE          | Hallo!          |
| 1       | ES          | ¡Hola!          |
| 2       | EN          | ....            |
| 2       | ES          | ....            |
-------------------------------------------
```

The combined primary key of this table is (textID, languageKey) preventing multiple translations of a topic in the same language.

Translated tables use InnoDb foreign key constraints for referencing all translations for a topic at once. Here the `text` column references `topicID` inside our translations table.

```
| id   | text |
---------------
| 100  | 1    |
| 101  | 2    |
---------------
```

The InnoDb table engine has following constraint, as written in the german documentation (translated because this piece of information is not contained in the english documentation):

> If multiple rows of a parent table have the same reference key, InnoDB behaves during foreign key integrity checks as if the other rows (with the same reference key) do not exists at all. For example, when having a `RESTRICT` type constraint on a foreign key InnoDB will prevent deletion of any rows that use a referenced key, event if other rows with the same referenced key exist.

This results in not being able to delete, e.g. the row from my translations table with key `1-ES`.

How can I avoid this InnoDB behavior? What would be the best approach? E.g. soft deletion by adding an `isDeleted` column to my translations? Or dropping all constraints and using TRIGGERS to ensure table integrity?

Any comments are appreciated.
David

---

PS: Here is the german quotation for the above translation:

> Abweichung von SQL-Standards: Wenn mehrere Zeilen in der Elterntabelle denselben Referenzschlüsselwert haben verhält sich InnoDB bei Fremdschlüsselprüfungen so, als würden die anderen Zeilen der Elterntabelle, also die mit demselben Schlüsselwert, gar nicht vorhanden. Wenn Sie beispielsweise einen RESTRICT-Typ-Constraint definiert haben und es eine Kindzeile mit mehreren Elternzeilen gibt, verbietet InnoDB das Löschen irgendeiner dieser Elternzeilen. [URL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html; Accessed: 2013/10/03]

Comment: These kinds of problems usually indicate a design error. Specifically, why is `text` referencing `topicID` and not the other way around?

Comment: The only shortcoming here is that it actually talks about allowing foreign key to reference something that is not unique -- different RDBMS (SQL Server, PostgreSQL) would raise an error.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic I chose the translations table as base table, because this prevents me from having translations-keys that do not belong to any translations (the other way around would not prevent that).

Comment: @DamirSudarevic My combined foreign key IS unique. Therefore it is a lack of the table engine with not fully supporting combined foreign keys. I think, that mathematically there is nothing that should prevent this behavior (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @david.schreiber Yes, but now you can have "dangling" translations (you can have a row in `translations` that is not connected to anything in `translated`).

Comment: @david.schreiber In your case, the referencing attribute happens to be unique. But the referencED attribute needs to be unique to avoid logical inconsistencies when updating/deleting referenced rows.